# Difference Between LostFocus Event and Leave Event of TextBox

Tags: c#-4.0

What is the difference between the `LostFocus` and the `Leave` events of `TextBox`?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/dd023378-d700-4c5f-a5b5-072fd4de7903

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Check the notes section on these links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave.aspx

According to MSDN, there is difference when changing focus of a control. The `Leave` event occurs before a validation and `LostFocus` occurs after validation.

---

***UPDATE: 14 Feb 2019***

I see that I'm still getting views and upvotes on the answer that I posted couple of years ago. It has now become imperative that I include a (rather important) quote from the MSDN links above to avoid confusion among new programmers (note the difference of order esp. in case of focus by using the mouse or by calling the `Focus` method):

> When you ***change the focus by using the keyboard*** (TAB, SHIFT+TAB, and
>   so on), by calling the Select or SelectNextControl methods, or by
>   setting the ContainerControl.ActiveControl property to the current
>   form, focus events occur in the following order:
>
> ```
> Enter
>
> GotFocus
>
> Leave              <--- before validation
>
> Validating      --
>                   |<--- validation
> Validated       --
>
> LostFocus          <--- after validation
> ```
>
> When you ***change the focus by using the mouse or by calling the Focus
>   method***, focus events occur in the following order:
>
> ```
> Enter
>
> GotFocus
>
> LostFocus          <--- before validation
>
> Leave              <--- before validation
>
> Validating      --
>                   |<--- validation
> Validated       --
> ```

<sup>**N.B:** Emphasis on text and indicators in the quote added by me</sup>

Answer (score 5):

They happen at different points in the control's lifecycle. Depending on the method used, validation happens after `Leave` and before `LostFocus`.

See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Leave() event means that first executes keyboard event and then executes mouse event where as Lost() event means that first executes mouse event and then executes keyboard event.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up, it either won't work for the keyboard or it won't work for the mouse. Considering you can't predict what input method will be used it's not very helpful.

However, that's not my point. LostFocus will happen when the form loads, Leave does not.

This would turn the text box yellow when the form is loaded.

```
Private Sub txtBox_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox.LostFocus
    txtBox.BackColor = Color.Yellow
End Sub
```

This would not.

```
Private Sub txtBox_TextLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox.Leave
    txtBox.BackColor = Color.Yellow
End Sub
```